# OOM when allocating tensor with shape[1,144,144,144,128]

Tags: python, image-processing, memory, machine-learning, gpu

The computer I use is 1080 which has a GPU memory of 8 GB, the memory of my computer is 32 GB, but the array data might be to large for me to restore, the computer tells me resource exhausted. if there is anyway to solve this problem or evaluate the GPU memory i need for such a large numpy array so I can buy a better computer for calculate.by the way the batch_size I use is 1 so i have reduce the memory to the minimal, or i should consider to reduce the raw column and the height of my numpy array, and I think that would effect the resolution of my results that would be okay.

If anyone can answer my question. thanks

Answer (score 1):

The tensor itself you are using is big, but not that big for a 8Gb GPU. `144 * 144 * 144 * 128` is ~380 million, so even with 32-bit items it requires 1.5GiB. I have a GeForce GTX 1070 with 8Gb (same size as you) and here's my Tensorflow experiment:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

X = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, shape=(1, 144, 144, 144, 128))
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as session:
  session.run(init)
  value = session.run([X], feed_dict={X: np.zeros(shape=(1, 144, 144, 144, 128))})
  print np.array(value).shape
```

The output:

```
name: GeForce GTX 1070
major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.7465
pciBusID 0000:01:00.0
Total memory: 7.92GiB
Free memory: 4.14GiB
2017-08-17 20:05:54.312424: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:908] DMA: 0 
2017-08-17 20:05:54.312430: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:918] 0:   Y 
2017-08-17 20:05:54.312444: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:977] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1070, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0)
(1, 1, 144, 144, 144, 128)
```

Note that free memory is much lower than 8Gb, because I use 2 UHD monitors. So this might be the first cause in your case: other processes can consume a lot of GPU resources.

Next, you didn't provide your Neural Network architecture, but if you are using, for instance, Deep Convolutional Neural Networks, note that the first layers are consuming a lot of memory for parameters and gradients. You might want to read [this helpful page for details](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/#layersizepat). If this is the case, you might need to plug in another GPU and split the graph across all available GPUs ([here's how you can do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313934/is-it-possible-to-split-a-network-across-multiple-gpus-in-tensorflow)). There are 12Gb memory GPUs available from NVidia.

Finally, you can always consider reducing the floating precision `tf.float64 -> tf.float32 -> tf.float16` for all your variables. This can save 8x memory, which sometimes is just enough to run on a GPU.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I have solved this problem by letting my boss buy a better machine. and the problem can be alleviated by using special more shallow net and using int32 or int16